# Form icon disappears from taskbar after form load

Tags: c#, winforms, taskbar

Following are the things i did and after that i got an issue of icon disappearing from task bar on form load

1. Added icon on win form application (Project->Property->icon)
2. build the solution and i got icon on exe file.
3. Added icon on form (form->property->icon)
4. build solution and run

When form loaded icon blinked on task bar for few milliseconds and then vanished

**What i tried**

1. Checked icon size (it is multiico)
2. Also tried icons with different sizes (16x16,24x24,32x32....256x256)

> Some times icon does not disappear , It is very unexpected behavior that often its invisible on task bar and sometimes its there

Can anybody guide me what i am missing?

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: @TheGeneral i did this but same issue blinked and then again disappear

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill Window 8.1

Comment: @TheGeneral one more thing i noticed . while application in running mode , opened explorer or other application and then minimize it . i got form icon on task bar.